# multiple IOS apps login with facebook

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using FBLoginView in my IOS app.
I built a second app for testing the next version (different bundle name) to co-exist with the production version.
When I click login with facebook, after permission validation I get the production app running instead of the new one.
I couldn't figure out from the documentation how can I solve this.
Pointing out to the right reference will be appreciated

Comment: Do they share the same facebook app id? If so, you can use a url scheme suffix to differentiate between your apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting

Comment: great. Thanks. I ended up creating a facebook test-app.
Just for future refrence - can I use this method it if I have FBLoginView?

Comment: yes, the suffix can be used for any iOS app that uses the SDK.